# How to redirect IE11 to a new page?

Tags: .htaccess, internet-explorer, redirect, internet-explorer-11

This works to redirect IE to a new page, but I only want to redirect IE11 to a new page.  Any ideas?

```
<!--[if IE]>
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.google.com">
<![endif]-->
```

This is the IE 11 user agent --> Mozilla/5.0 (IE 11.0; Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; rv:11.0) like Gecko

Comment: anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

in htaccess in the document root :

```
RewriteEngine on


 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} IE11 [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ http://google.com/ [L,R]
```

Comment: I placed the above code in the domains htaccess file however all the IE11 visitors are still coming, not redirected to my chosen domain.  Any other ideas how to block IE11 visitors?

Comment: Try placing at  top (before other RewriteRules)

Comment: Yes, this is where I had placed the code to begin with, above the other rewrite rules in htaccess.  Anybody else know how to redirect all IE11 visitors to another page?